# How to extract testing creation logic into a shared method

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have code I want to extract from a unit test to make my test method clearer:

```
Check check;
check.Amount = 44.00;

// unit testing on the check goes here
```

How should I extract this?  Should I use a pointer to the check or some other structure to make sure it's still allocated when I use the object?

I don't want to use a constructor because I want to isolate my test creation logic with production creation logic.

Comment: which unit testing framework? Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

In a modern unit testing framework you usually have testing case as

```
class MyTest: public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
  MyTest() {}
  ~MyTest() {}
  virtual void SetUp() {
    // this will be invoked just before each unit test of the testcase
    // place here any preparations or data assembly
    check.Amount = 44.00;
  }
  virtual void TearDown() {
    // this will be inkoved just after each unit test of the testcase
    // place here releasing of data
  }
  // any data used in tests
  Check check;
};

// single test that use your predefined preparations and releasing
TEST_F(MyTest, IsDefaultInitializedProperly) {
  ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ(44., check.Amount);
}
// and so on, SetUp and TearDown will be done from scratch for every new test
```

You can find such functionality i.e. in Google Test Framework (https://github.com/google/googletest/)